# if else for more than one date result

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, next.js

How do you use an `if else` to see if there is more than one `dates` result?

```
<If condition={adv_event.dates > 0 }>
  <Then>
    <p>More than one</p>
  </Then>
  <Else>
    {adv_event.dates.length > 0 ? (
      <div className="col-md-4">
        {adv_event.dates &&
          <DateField props={adv_event.dates} />
        }
      </div>
    ) : ''}
  </Else>
</If>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's simple use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {

    state = {
        adv_event :{
      data: 10
      }
    }


  render() {
  const {adv_event:{data}} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {data >0? <div><p>More than one</p></div> : <div><p>no data</p></div>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

here is a quick [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/blueseal/L9jkf1ao/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to look like this

```
<React.Fragment>
{adv_event.dates 
? (
    <p>More than one</p>
) 
: adv_event.dates.length && (
    <div className="col-md-4">
        {adv_event.dates && <DateField props={adv_event.dates} />}
    </div>
)}
</React.Fragment>
```